# How can you remove only the interaction terms in a polynomial regression using scikit-learn?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

I am running a [polynomial regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) using scikit-learn. I have a large number of variables (23 to be precise) which I am trying to regress using polynomial regression with degree 2.

interaction_only = True, keeps only the interaction terms such as X<sub>1</sub>*Y<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>*Y<sub>2</sub>, and so on.

I want only the other terms i.e, X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>,  Y<sub>1</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, and so on.

Is there a function to get this?

Comment: It's weird sklearn still doesn't have this. Many times we want to try polynomial features without interaction.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such function, because the transormation can be easily expressed with numpy itself.

```
X = ... 
new_X = np.hstack((X, X**2))
```

and analogously if you want to add everything up to degree `k`

```
new_X = np.hstack((X**(i+1) for i in range(k)))
```

Comment: I was using the following.

`poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
 X_new = poly.fit_trnasform(X)`

Since X was a list of 100 odd lists of size 23 each, X_new would be a matrix with each row corresponding to all combinations leading to degree 2.

So, as per your answer, I would need to manually create this matrix by iterating through X and using np.hstack and np.vstack

Is my deduction correct?

Comment: I'll do you one better: `np.power(x, np.arange(k))`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is super old. But for folks like me who just getting started can use petsy. Checkout the answer discussed here ->
[how to the remove interaction-only columns from sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716574/how-to-the-remove-interaction-only-columns-from-sklearn-preprocessing-polynomial)

Comment: Please, consider posting a comment next time, instead of a proper answer :)