# how to the remove interaction-only columns from sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessor, polynomials, non-linear-regression

As per the description given below: 'if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].'

[sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.set_params)

I need my output ndarray generated to be of the type: [a, b, a^2, b^2]
I know that `poly = PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False)
poly.fit_transform(X)`
gives the output like : [a, b, a^2, ab, b^2]. But I do not want these intermediate 'ab' type columns that are being generated. How to do that any idea? Or any better API that can be used here?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [patsy](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) and this scikit-learn integration [patsylearn](https://github.com/amueller/patsylearn).

This gives you full control in a R-like formula:

```
from patsylearn import PatsyTransformer
transformer = PatsyTransformer("y ~ a + b + a^2 + b^2")
transformer.fit(data)
```